# RecyclerView não expande

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Olá,  é o seguinte, estou usando duas RecyclerView em paralelo:

```
              <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/produtos"
                >
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/refeicoes"
                >
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Eu faço duas pesquisas diferentes e coloco lá.
O Problema é que parece que o RecyclerView produtos não expande por total. Parece que ela fica rodando no mesmo eixo.
Eu queria que ela expandisse. Se tivesse 30 produtos, mostrasse os 30 e aí mostrasse a RecycLerView refeicoes.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Obrigada.

Comment: Você precisa de uma RecyclerView dentro da outra? Isso não costuma dar muito certo.

Comment: Oi Pablo, não está dentro da outra. Está em seguida. Você tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: A `refeicoes` e a sem nome estão dentro da `produtos`.

Comment: São só duas, arrumei a formatação

Comment: O que seria rodar no mesmo eixo?

Comment: Não seria uma ExpandableListView?(uma lista expansível)